# Ubuntu Core for Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: raspberrypi

I am trying to setup Raspberry Pi Zero W with Ubuntu Core (Snappy). I checked the download page, but it doesn't show image for RPi Zero.

Anyone know if Ubuntu Core (Snappy) can be loaded to Raspberry Pi Zero W ?

Answer (score 3):

The Raspberry Pi 0 and 0 W use the same chip as the original Raspberry Pi and Pi Ab/+.  It's an ARM v6 architecture, which Ubuntu no longer supports.  Snappy and Snappy core definitely don't run on it (they're relatively new releases/distros).

DDG was happy to give a concise answer when I [searched](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=raspberry%20pi%200%20ubuntu&t=ffsb&ia=qa).

There's also a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703070/does-ubuntu-work-on-a-raspberry-pi-zero) here that goes in depth to the answer.